# Invoke-WebRequest Powershell does not end

Tags: php, powershell, post, httpwebrequest

When running a post request:

```
$postParams = @{key='testing'}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://url.com/page.php -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

The server receives the POST request (adds to SQL database), but the command doesn't 'timeout' or end. I think this is because it doesn't receive a response? I've tried with `-timeoutsec 1` but this is too big of a delay, is there a way to have this as milliseconds? as this would also work.

Any help would be appreciated, the PHP code is simply:

```
<html>
<?php
require 'connect.php';
if ($_POST){
    # need to find way of getting victimID
    $sql = "INSERT INTO keysTable VALUES(NULL,'".$_POST['key']."', '1','2022-08-22 08:56:39')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
}
echo 'helo world';
var_dump($_POST);
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe call `flush(); exit();` at the end of the php script?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen just tried with both, the powershell script continues to run:(